# Server Socket blocks after first recived data

Tags: java, sockets

I want to ask why the server is showing only the first time one of the clients send data ,my intent is to have two clients and just want to send some integer ,the server to read it and then send it back to the other client and then to wait the this client to send info and send it to the other client (toggling them).But only the first time the data is sended ,it is read on the server ?

Server :

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Server {

    private ServerSocket serv;
    private DataInputStream inFromClient1;
    private DataOutputStream outToClient1;
    private DataInputStream inFromClient2;
    private DataOutputStream outToClient2;

    public Server(){
        try {
            serv=new ServerSocket(8000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void listen() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Listening for connections");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while(true){
                    Socket sock1;
                    Socket sock2;
                    try {
                        sock1 = serv.accept();
                        sock2=serv.accept();
                        handleSession(sock1,sock2);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
    public void handleSession(Socket s1,Socket s2) throws IOException{
        DataInputStream in1=new DataInputStream(s1.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out1=new DataOutputStream(s1.getOutputStream());

        DataInputStream in2=new DataInputStream(s1.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out2=new DataOutputStream(s1.getOutputStream());
        while(true){

            int inint1=in1.readInt();
            System.out.println("Recived from 1 " + inint1);
            System.out.println("Sending to 2 ");
            out2.writeInt(in1.readInt());
            int inint2=in2.readInt();
            System.out.println("Recived from 2 " + inint2);
            System.out.println("Sending to 1 ");
            out1.writeInt(inint2);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Server().listen();
    }
}

Client : 

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Client extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JButton[] buttons;
    private Socket socket;
    private int number;
    private DataInputStream fromServer;
    private DataOutputStream toServer;
    private boolean myTurn=true;

    public Client() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        mainPanel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));
        socket=new Socket("localhost",8000);
        add(mainPanel);
        addbuttons();
        setSize(new Dimension(500,400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addbuttons(){
        buttons=new JButton[9];
        for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
            buttons[i-1]=new JButton("Rectangle " + i);
            buttons[i-1].addActionListener(this);
            mainPanel.add(buttons[i-1]);
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JButton butt=(JButton) arg0.getSource();
        String str=butt.getText();
        String[] splitStr=str.split(" ");
        number=Integer.parseInt(splitStr[1]);
        System.out.println(number);
    }

    public void start() throws IOException{
        fromServer=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        toServer=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
                while(true){
                    System.out.println("Write some integer");
                    int inint=in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Before " + myTurn);
                    if(myTurn){
                        try {
                            toServer.writeInt(inint);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        myTurn=false;
                    }
                    else{
                        int fromServint=0;
                        try {
                            fromServint=fromServer.readInt();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Recived integer " + fromServint);
                        buttons[fromServint].setText("Some new Text");
                        myTurn=true;
                    }
                    System.out.println("After " + myTurn);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        new Client().start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're reading 2 integers from client 1 (guessing it's a typo) so

try changing

```
out2.writeInt(in1.readInt());
```

to

```
out2.writeInt(inint1);
```

Also, as @JohnBollinger mentioned,

> Separate Data*Streams are created, but both sets are connected to socket s1, instead of one set to each socket.

```
    DataInputStream in1=new DataInputStream(s1.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream out1=new DataOutputStream(s1.getOutputStream());

    DataInputStream in2=new DataInputStream(s1.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream out2=new DataOutputStream(s1.getOutputStream());
```

All streams here are referencing the same client.

Comment: Additionally, @dogbranch, the server appears to be connecting both sets of streams to the same client.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It appears to be that the clients/streams are distinct, perhaps you're mistaken?

Comment: Look again.  Separate Data*Streams are created, but both sets are connected to socket `s1`, instead of one set to each socket.

Answer (score 0):

You are using blocking sockets. For that reason, when you call any kind of "read" method, it will block until data is received from the client.

So, one thread is not enough. The first read will block, the second read will never be executed unless the first client actually sent something.

Solution 1: Use one thread per socket connection (recommended, because easier).
Solution 2: Use non-blocking sockets (not recommended, difficult but good for certain performance critical scenarios).

Comment: You meant ,on the server ,I should start new thread for every client ?

Comment: @dobrgranch, Ideally you should have 2 threads, one that listens, and one that parses requests/responds. For small projects it is (somewhat) acceptable to have one thread per client; but it can turn into a serious performance issue with n threads spawning.

Comment: Yes, on the server start one thread per client connection (= socket) and do all read/write processing in the client-specific thread.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
int inint1=in1.readInt();
System.out.println("Recived from 1 " + inint1);
System.out.println("Sending to 2 ");
out2.writeInt(in1.readInt());
```

First you read an `int` from the first client. Then you print some stuff and read a second `int` from the same client. But the client waits for a `int` from the server and therefore sends no second, so the server blocks.
Replace the last line of the code above with `out2.writeInt(inint1);` and see if it works. I haven't read all of the code, so I am not sure if there is another mistake.